# How old should bearded dragons be when you adopt them?

Tags: reptiles, adoption, bearded-dragon, age

So we know that it's bad to get dogs and cats when they're younger than 8 weeks old, but what about bearded dragons? Is there a certain age that you should wait for your bearded dragon to be before getting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really a set age to adopt a bearded dragon at, because like most reptiles they don't care for their young after they hatch. What you're going to want to consider is how much time you have to care for it, and your experience with reptiles.

Juvenile bearded dragons need more care than adult bearded dragons, because they're more fragile being so small. You will have to take special care as they grow and shed their old skin, making sure that it all goes well and none of it stays behind.

They also will need to be fed more than adults, and more insects. While adults are mostly herbivorous, juveniles will be mostly carnivorous and need to be fed three times a day to adult's two times a day.

If you have experience with reptiles already, and have the time to devote to them, by all means get a baby bearded dragon, they are quite adorable when they're tiny. But if it's the first reptile you're getting, or you aren't sure you have the time to care for them as much, then I would suggest purchasing one that's closer to 10 inches in length, as that will be young adult and slightly easier to care for.